# Testing an interactive module with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python module which is designed to be used by non-programmers, interactively. It is used within iPython, and on load, it asks for a couple of user inputs, prints some ascii art, that sort of thing. This is implemented in the `__init__.py` of the module.

The module also contains a utils file `tld(containing setup.py)/utils.py`, with some functions in it.  I would like to test these. The utils file does not import anything from the rest of the module, and contains only pure functions. The tests live in `tld(containing setup.py)/tests/test_utils.py`Currently, trying to run pytest results in a failure, as the module's `__init__` file is run, which hangs whilst awaiting the above mentioned user input.

Is there a way of getting pytest to run the tests in test_utils.py, without running the `__init__.py` of the python module? Or some other way of getting around this issue?

I have tried running `pytest tests/test_utils.py`, but that had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining an `initialize` function inside the `__init__.py` of the module, which encapsulates all of the user interaction. If `module.initialize()` is not explicitly called, no user input is requested, so the pytest tests can run as expected.